# Can i use existing card.uri for future to pay payment in balance payments?

Tags: balanced-payments

I am using `Balance payment system` to pay using credit cards in apps.

When user `pay using credit cards` in balance payments i get `card.uri`

If user want to use same credit card in future without enter card info can i use `user.uri` for that?

Means can i use same credit card for payment without enter credit card info again.

any one have a solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I `solved` my issue. See below code:

```
buyer = Balanced::Account.find(account_uri)
card = buyer.cards[0]
debit = buyer.debit(amount_in_sent, "MARKETPLACE.COM", :source_uri => card.uri)
```

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what payment system you're using but from what you're writing it sounds like `user.uri` is a link that you can use when the same user is going to pay again. It's not that all payment data is stored but maybe some of it. Sometimes when a payment provider is "storing" your payment data you still have to re-enter the code on the back of the card because they don't store everything. So maybe `user.uri` is a user specific link to a page where the user only has to enter those digits. If this is the case then you need to store this `user.uri` for each and every user because each and every user will have their own unique user.uri. Don't mix them up because then you'll have a security problem.

I hope it gave you some clarity in how it might work.